# Creating new object inside class

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I'm still learning about OOP and dependency injection and there's something that I'm struggling with.

Below is a simple class that has a separate database class injected through the constructor and uses the getAll method to return all articles from the database. I understand that DI is prefered and is best practice as it makes the class easy to test with unit testing and decouples it etc.

```
class Articles {
    private $Database;

    public function __construct(Database $database) {
        $this->Database = $database;
    }
    public function getAll() {
        return $this->Database->query("SELECT * FROM Articles");
    }
}
```

But what if I want to iterate over all those items in the array and instantiate a new class for each item inside another class? (Which in this case would be a new task that would then be put in the task queue.) I can inject the queue class and reuse that but I can't inject the Task class as I'm instantiating multiple instances of it, so I'm currently instantiating it directly inside the class without injecting it which is bad. Like so:

```
class Articles {
    private $Database;
    private $Queue;

    public function __construct(Database $database, Queue $queue) {
        $this->Database = $database;
        $this->Queue = $queue;
    }
    public function init() {
        $tasks = [];
        $articles = $this->getAll():
        foreach ($articles as $article) {
            $item = new Task($article);
            $tasks[] = $item;
        }
        $queue = $this->Queue($tasks);
    }
    public function getAll() {
        return $this->Database->query("SELECT * FROM Articles");
    }
}
```

So how do I accomplish what I desire? I could instantiate the classes inside a controller, but that means deliberately building logic to expose the iterable array to the controller when I'd like it to be done in the init method of the class so all the logic is grouped together.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to add a "list" class, or a collection or whatever you want to call it, which can contain multiple "tasks", or "URLs" or whatever (different lists/collections/groups). This way the list can be injected and you can populate it with individual instances of each data model type as you go.

Answer (score 0):

If `Task` is just used to represent data, then it will not change and no need to inject it..

Anyway a solution to your problem is to use the `Builder` design pattern, inject the builder and use it to build your object.

```
// Abstract class for the builder
abstract class BaseTaskBuilder {

abstract public function build();
}

//Concrete class for builder
class GreatTaskBuilder extends BaseTaskBuilder{
public function build() {
// return a new instance of GreatTask
}
}

// Abstract class for task
abstract class BaseTask{}

// Concrete class for task
class GreatTask extends BaseTask{}
```

So, all what you have to do is to inject the builder, as you do in your code.

Comment: But doesn't the problem still remain that I'd have to instantiate the model object inside a class?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep my model clean.

`Article` is a data model where you have your usual `CRUD` functions `update()`, `retrive()`, `delete()`, `insert`, `getAll()` , `getOne($id)` etc ...

It is fine to injec `Database`,  but not really the `Queue` at that point it is not really a model.

Instead of building task and queues in your model, you should create a service class that would take care of that process and use dependency injection there as well.

This will make unit test a lot easier

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to provide an example of what the service class might look like in this scenario?